# Out of sync divx movie when playing on car player

Tags: video, portable, codec

What causes out-of sync when playing DivX movies on portable / car player ?
I think it has something to do with how the movies are encoded, so here's the MediaInfo comparison of both movie file.

```
============================================================================
Video
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Items             | OutOfSync.avi            | Sync.avi         
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Format              | MPEG-4 Visual            | MPEG-4 Visual
  Format profile      | Advanced Simple@L5       | Advanced Simple@L5
  Format settings     |                          |
     BVOP             | Yes                      | Yes
     QPel             | No                       | No
     GMC              | No warppoints            | No warppoints
     Matrix           | Default (H.263)          | Default (H.263)
  Codec ID            | XVID                     | XVID
  Codec ID/Hint       | XviD                     | XviD
  Duration            | 21mn 5s                  | 21mn 6s
  Bit rate            | 1 016 Kbps               | 1 017 Kbps
  Width               | 624 pixels               | 624 pixels
  Height              | 352 pixels               | 352 pixels
  Display ratio       | 16:09                    | 16:09
  Frame rate          | 23.976 fps               | 23.976 fps
  Color space         | YUV                      | YUV
  Chroma subsampling  | 4:02:00                  | 4:02:00
  Bit depth           | 8 bits                   | 8 bits
  Scan type           | Progressive              | Progressive
  Bits/(Pixel*Frame)  | 0.193                    | 0.193
  Stream size         | 153 MiB (88%)            | 154 MiB (88%)
  Writing library     | XviD 1.2.1               | XviD 1.2.1 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Audio  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Items             |    OutOfSync.avi         |  Sync.avi         
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Format              | MPEG Audio               | MPEG Audio
     version          | Version 1                | Version 1
     profile          | Layer 3                  | Layer 3
  Mode                | Joint stereo             | Joint stereo
  Mode extension      | MS Stereo                | MS Stereo
  Codec ID            | 55                       | 55
  Codec ID/Hint       | MP3                      | MP3
  Duration            | 21mn 5s                  | 21mn 6s
  Bit rate mode       | Variable                 | Variable
  Bit rate            | 128 Kbps                 | 128 Kbps
  Channel(s)          | 2 channels               | 2 channels
  Sampling rate       | 48.0 KHz                 | 48.0 KHz
  Bit depth           | 16 bits                  | 16 bits
  Stream size         | 19.7 MiB (11%)           | 19.6 MiB (11%)
  Alignment           | Aligned on interleaves   | Aligned on interleaves
  Interleave duration | 24 ms (0.58 video frame) | 24 ms (0.58 video frame)
  Writing library     | LAME3.92                 | LAME3.92
  Encoding settings   | -m j -V 4 -q 2 -lowpass  | -m j -V 4 -q 2 -lowpass 
                      | 17.5 --abr               | 17.5 --abr
============================================================================
```

I notice that the only difference in those two file is **Video Bit Rate** (1016 and 1017), **Video Stream Size** (153 Mib and 154 Mib), and **Audio Stream Size** (19.7 MiB and 19.6 MiB). Are those things enough to make out of sync video play on car player? Both files play perfectly fine on my laptop. Are there any tools that I can be use to change the out of sync file?

Answer (score 1):

From [Why does your system have audio/video sync issues?](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/112800-Why-does-your-system-have-audio-video-sync-issues), the following reasons can cause sync problems when capturing video:

> 1. Is your hard drive fast enough?
> 2. Are you capturing to your primary hard drive?
> 3. Do you have a VIA chipset?
> 4. Are you sure your system is configured correctly?
> 5. Are you viewing the final mpeg with Windows Media Player?
> 6. Do you have an onboard soundcard?
> 7. How reliable is your source?

To fix sync problems, from [Divx audio out of sync. help!](http://forum.digital-digest.com/showthread.php?t=53858) :

> **If the difference between audio and video is constant throughout the
>   video**
>
> - Load the file into VirtualDub,    VirtualDubMod, or NanDub.
> - Set BOTH "Video"(VirtualDub,    VirtualDubMod and NanDub) and "Audio" 
>     (VirtualDub and NanDub -
>     VirtualDubMOD>"Streams>"Stream list") 
>     to "Direct Stream Copy".
> - From the "Audio" dropdown menu, select "Interleaving" (For 
>     VirtualDubMOD, rightclick on the 
>     listed audiostream and then select 
>     "Interleaving")
> - Under "Audio skew correction", set an    appropriate number of
>     milliseconds    positive in the box
>     labeled "Delay audio track by"
> - Save with a new file-name
>
> **If the difference increases as the movie plays**
>
> - From under the "Video" dropdown menu, select "Framerate" - and
>     select "Change so video and audio durations match"
> - Save with a new file-name
>
> keep in mind 1000 milliseconds is 1
>   sec, so use this as an idea of what
>   value to enter....i find a lot of
>   times 300 seems to be the magic

Comment: It's not really what I'm asking, but thanks for the info anyway.

Comment: I believe there are only two possibilities: (1) video encoding : which can be improved as I described, and (2) the car player badly handles files of a certain format which may require more processing power than it has. Software-wise, I can only address the first item. A video file has a very complex structure and can be badly (or awkwardly) constructed, for reasons which I have also outlined above. Re-encoding by a good utility might simplify its structure.